# Dynamically wait for a task in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have  a bunch of task which i need to run through python list . Some task take two seconds and some tasks takes as munch as 10 seconds . When i execute the list in for loop i give time max as 10 seconds . However i would like to use dynamic wait as some tasks in list take 2 seconds also

I am able to only achieve this with static wait with longest time taken by a task in list  , so in below case "no shut" takes 10 seconds hence i am using 10 seconds

```
config_3 = ['c t', 'int gi0/3', 'no shut']

for i in config_3:
      time.sleep(10)  # ---> this needs to be converted in dynamic wait
      tn1.write(i.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
```

**Expected Outcome:**
expectation here is that other two elements other than "no shut" should not spent 10 seconds and get completed dynamically in 2 seconds

**Observed Outcome:**
Observed outcome is all tasks execute in 10 seconds as static sleep is applied

Comment: Do you have to run the tasks in sequence? 
Why don't you start the next task after the completion of the current one? 
If you have predetermined execution times, why don't you assign each task a duration and wait that amount when said task is running. 
Please provide more info about your situation. 
Did you remove the code that executes the task before waiting?

Comment: Hi, Yes i do need to run them in for loop and achieve it this way . I have only given 10 seconds as static wait to execute the same

Comment: Why do you need to provide a wait time instead of starting the next task upon the completion of the current one? Also, what determines the amount of time to wait?

Comment: Please provide some clarity on why you have to have the wait times for clarity. There may be a better way to achieve your goal

Comment: some commands are slow to execute, some commands are fast to be executed on device

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If you want us to help, please answer all the questions and add more details to your question.

Comment: I created a pip installable library which waits with a timeout until a certain function has a desired return value. Its currently in Alpha but could be functional for you. https://pypi.org/project/wait-for-it-to/